# Is there a cap for the number of Verpflichtungserklärung one can request for friends and family members?

Tags: visa, germany, family, schengen

As per [§§ 66 - 68 German Residence Act](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_aufenthg/englisch_aufenthg.html#p1210), a German resident got the option to provide his/her third-country friends and family members with a formal obligation document (Verpflichtungserklärung) to assist their visa application.

I was wondering if there's a cap for the number of Verpflichtungserklärung one can request at once and/or during a year? In other words, how many people you can invite to visit per year? In there a cap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my question, there seem to be no time-bound cap for a letter of commitment a German resident can provide.

However, there seem to be a maximum cap of 4 persons one can invite at once. The number of guests you can provide a Verpflichtungserklärung for depends on either host's income. Spouses can also chip in case that one's income is not enough.

[image: Income requirements]

More information here:
https://www.muenchen.de/dienstleistungsfinder/muenchen/1063743/